# Downloading 64-bit applications doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, kernel, 20.04, raspberrypi, arm64

I tried downloading a 64-bit Linux program onto my Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04 and it does not work. I am attempting to install 'NI-488 Linux' on to the 64-bit computer and it isn't recognizing the computer as a 64-bit computer. The error message I received after trying to mount the .iso file is listed below.

Error message:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cd /mnt/disk
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt/disk$ ls -l
total 89864
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root     2048 Apr  5  2017 Documentation
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root   107571 Apr  5  2017 INSTALL
-r--r--r-- 1 root root    22683 Apr  5  2017 LICENSE.txt
dr-xr-xr-x 4 root root     2048 Apr  5  2017 NI-VISA
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 91776429 Apr  5  2017 NI4882-17.0.0f0.tar.gz
-r--r--r-- 1 root root    23527 Apr  5  2017 PATENTS.txt
-r--r--r-- 1 root root    35642 Apr  5  2017 README.txt
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root    49091 Apr  5  2017 UNINSTALL
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt/disk$ sudo ./INSTALL

*****************************************************************************
  NI-488.2
     version 17.0.0f0 for Linux
*****************************************************************************

NI-488.2 supports the following Linux distributions:
   CentOS
   openSUSE
   Red Hat Enterprise Linux
   Scientific Linux
Refer to README.txt for the latest information at the time of release.
Refer to www.ni.com/linux for the most recent information about Linux
support at National Instruments.


This installer does not support 32-bit kernels.
ubuntu@ubuntu:/mnt/disk$
```

I've been trying to get this program installed for about a month but no luck. Any helpful suggestions would highly be appreciated.

Comment: The error text says that it doesn't support Ubuntu (only CentOS, openSUSE and Red Hat EL) , and not 32 bit kernels either.

Comment: FYI: Raspberry Pi will always identify as `arm64` or `armhf` - ARM64 and ARMHF are *not* the same as x86_64 processors (amd64, used by current AMD and Intel processors).

Answer (score 0):

The error lists:

```
supports the following Linux distributions:
CentOS
openSUSE
Red Hat Enterprise Linux
Scientific Linux
```

So no Ubuntu/Debian listed there and then also states:

```
This installer does not support 32-bit kernels.
```

So its mainly due to the software does not support Ubuntu/Debian.

Comment: And quite possibly not the ARM-based Raspberry Pi environments.  (Because ARM is not the same as Intel/AMD x64-based processors)

Comment: are there any platforms out there that you'd recommend that could run visa communications so that i could communicate with other hardware equipment through gpib using the pi?

Comment: The ones listed in the error are the supported platforms